# How to do Two Way binding within two combo boxes in Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, data-binding

In a project I am showing two ComboBoxes lets say ComboBox1 and ComboBox2. I am binding both the ComboBox with a KeyValue pair Dictionary lets say dictionary1 as given below.

```
ComboBox1.ItemsSource = dictionary1 ;
ComboBox1.SelectedItem = ComboBox1.Items[0];

//Setting the Item Source of Patient Name Combo Box.
ComboBox2.ItemsSource = dictionary1 ;
ComboBox2.SelectedItem = ComboBox2.Items[0];
```

and in the XAML part, I am showing Key in the CombBox1 and Value in the ComboBox2 of the Dictionary as mentioned below:-

```
<ComboBox
       x:Name             ="ComboBox1"
       DisplayMemberPath  ="Key"
       SelectedValue      ="{Binding Source=ComboBox2, Path=DisplayMemberPath, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<ComboBox
       x:Name              ="ComboBox2"
       DisplayMemberPath   ="Value"
       SelectionChanged    ="ComboBox2_SelectionChanged"
       />
```

**Objective:-**
If I change the selection in ComboBox1 then it should affect the corresponding value of the ComboBox2.SelectedItem and also if I change the selection in ComboBox2 then it should affect the corresponding key value in the ComboBox1.SelectedItem.

Can anybody tell me where is the mistake in my above code or please help me in accomplish the above said objective. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have error in binging. DisplayMemberPath of combobox 2 contains string value "Value", so in your binging you trying to set something like combobox1.SelectedValue = combobox1.DisplayMemberPath, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
<ComboBox
       x:Name             ="ComboBox1"
       DisplayMemberPath  ="Key"
       SelectedItem      ="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox2, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<ComboBox
       x:Name              ="ComboBox2"
       DisplayMemberPath   ="Value"
       />
```

Comment: dbaseman, I think there should be Mode=TwoWay, otherwise it's not working for me. Thanks all for quick answer

Comment: dbaseman, in SL be default Mode has OneWay binding, not like in WPF TwoWay.

Answer (score 1):

I can see at least two problems:

1. Needs to be *ElementName* instead of *Source*
2. Should be *Path* instead of *DisplayMemberPath*

I think this should work:

```
<ComboBox
   x:Name             ="ComboBox1"
   DisplayMemberPath  ="Key"
   SelectedValue      ="{Binding ElementName=ComboBox2, Path=SelectedValue}"/>

<ComboBox
   x:Name             ="ComboBox2"
   DisplayMemberPath  ="Value" />
```